# How to grep a string ignoring punctuation?

Tags: grep

I have a >100MB text file of company names and their code like below:

```
...  
...  
ABC Sys, INC.:0001111111:  
ABC Systems INC:0001111112:  
...  
...
```

I have an input company name `abc sys inc` (without the comma after Sys and period after Inc).

I want to grep the line having company name `ABC Sys, Inc.` using search string `abc sys inc`.

```
grep -i "abc sys inc" my_list_file.txt
```

returns no lines, whereas I want it to return the first line.

```
grep -i "abc sys" my_list_file.txt
```

returns both lines.

Comment: You need at least something like `grep -i "abc[[:space:][:punct:]]\+sys[[:space:][:punct:]]\+inc" my_list_file.txt` or `grep -E -i "abc[^[:alnum:]]+sys[^[:alnum:]]+inc" my_list_file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace each space with a pattern that would match 1 or more punctuation/whitespace characters. So, you may use either `[[:space:][:punct:]]\+` / `[[:space:][:punct:]]\{1,\}` or `[^[:alnum:]]\+` / `[^[:alnum:]]\{1,\}`. If you use a POSIX ERE expression, the `\+` or `\{1,\}` can be written as a mere `+`.

```
search="abc sys inc";
grep -E -i "${search// /[^[:alnum:]]+}" file > outfile
```

See the [`grep` demo](https://ideone.com/berpQt):

```
s='...  
ABC Sys, INC.:0001111111:  
ABC Systems INC:0001111112:  
...  '

search="abc sys inc";
grep -E -i "${search// /[^[:alnum:]]+}" <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
ABC Sys, INC.:0001111111:
```

Comment: Using ```cat my_list_file.txt``` in place of ```"$s"``` worked for me. Just noting here because my question was about grepping a >100MB file.

Comment: @Sri `grep` accepts a filepath after pattern argument, you never need `cat` with `grep`

Comment: Ah, one tends to miss basic stuff tinkering with complicated ones. So, just ```my_list_file.txt``` in place of ```<<< "$s"``` it is.